# Как найти совпадение комбинации при вычислении факториала?

Tags: c#

пишу программку которая бы выводила факториал числа и возможные комбинации букв. При первом же совпадении выводила, что на такой то итерации произошло совпадение.
Написал уже вот такой код.

```
static int Factorial(int x)
    {
        return (x == 0 || x == 1) ? 1 : x * Factorial(x - 1);
    }

    static string Combinations(int combination_count, int combination_length)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        string result = "";

        string variants = "ABCDE";

        for(int i = 0; i < combination_count; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < combination_length; j++)
            {
                result += variants[rnd.Next(0,variants.Length)];


            }


            result += "\n";
        }


        return result;
    }
```

В функцию Combinations передаю функцию Factorial и вторым параметром передаю число от которого считается Factorial. Сейчас выводится не то что нужно, так как Random может вывести строку состоящую из одних букв E. 
Update. Вызывается все вот так.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Combinations(Factorial(5),5));
   Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

На выходе получаю это:
[image: Что то пошло не так]

Comment: Что и как вызываете? Какого результата ожидаете при этом? И какой результат фактически получается? Пока ничего не понятно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Результат я хочу получить, что бы в консоли вывелись варианты комбинации из пяти букв в количестве 120. Если говорить про факториал от 5. В принципе меня только от 5 и интересует. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Телепатия подсказывает, что автор хочет сгенерировать перестановки. Чего именно - символов ''ABCDE'' без повторов? А вот про совпадение чего-то с чем-то - неясненько....

Comment: @MBo  для 3 к примеру получить 6 таких перестановок: (1 2 3), (1 3 2), (2 1 3), (2 3 1), (3 1 2) и (3 2 1). Только вместо цифр буквы.

Comment: А при чем тогда Random? Если вам нужны все возможные перестановки

Comment: @АндрейNOP А как тогда правильно поступить? У меня изначально была задумка, что Рандом будет конструировать строку, но перед добавлением нового символа в строку, будет проверка а есть ли повторение символа. Что бы не было двух букв А или Е. Любой другой.

Comment: Проще всего сделать рекурсивную функцию, которая принимает строку. В цикле отщепляем от стоки один символ и запускаем эту же функцию, передавая строку с вырезанным этим символом

Comment: Материалов по генерации перестановок (permutation) в сети море. Лучше всего найти c# реализацию алгоритма `nextpemutation`, она ещё не раз пригодится. Если лексикографический порядок не нужен, гляньте весьма эффективный https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm

Comment: @MBo спасибо за ссылку. Буду изучать.